# Query multiple content dynamic content type in single query [which will return common properties of the types queries]

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-4.0, sitefinity

Is it some how possible to Query multiple content dynamic content type in single query [which will return common properties of the types queries].
What I have is four different dynamic content type with some common properties. want's to query them on bases of one common type [publisheddate] and some paging filters.
I am using sitefinity 6.3

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is take the various different dynamic content types or even built in Sitefinity content types and translate them to the same type, then you have a single collection to work from. Its not in single query but maybe it will help you out.

Create a common type that contains all the fields that your other types have:

```
public class CommonType
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public DateTime Published { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a method that converts them:

```
public static IEnumerable<CommonType> GetEverything()
{
    var commonTypes = new List<CommonType>();

    var articles = GetArticles(); //boilerplate code from Administration -> Module Builder -> {Your Module} -> Code Refrence


    foreach (var article in articles)
    {
        commonTypes.Add(new CommonType
        {
            Title = article.GetValue<Lstring>("Title"),
            Published = article.PublicationDate,
            Summary = article.GetValue<Lstring>("Summary")
        });
    }

    var bPosts = GetBlogPosts(); //method to get blog posts using the Sitefinity API

    foreach (var post in bPosts)
    {
        commonTypes.Add(new CommonType
        {
            Title = post.Title,
            Published = post.PublicationDate,
            Summary = post.Summary
        });
    }


    var whitepapers = GetWhitepapers(); //boilerplate code from Administration -> Module Builder -> {Your Module} -> Code Refrence

    foreach (var whitepaper in whitepapers)
    {
        commonTypes.Add(new CommonType
        {
            Title = whitepaper.GetValue<Lstring>("Title"),
            Published = whitepaper.PublicationDate,
            Summary = whitepaper.GetValue<Lstring>("Summary"),
        });
    }

    return commonTypes;
}
```

Now you can do something like:

```
var commonTypes = GetEverything().OrderBy(c => c.Published).Take(10);
```

Comment: Want's to avoid querying multiple time. this above solution is will effect the performance a lot

Comment: You could try caching the list of common types, otherwise I'd look at Josh's solution, if the properties are named the same on all the modules I think his solution would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I recently blogged about querying dynamic modules so you can do things with them in a generic way, take a look here:

http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/josh-morales/2014/03/06/querying-the-list-of-sitefinity-dynamic-modules-and-types

I hope this is helpful!

Comment: no josh. Ben has understand it correctly but it do same thing of querying different sources then combine the result.